# How does Heroic Feat resolution actually work?

Tags: castle-falkenstein

After reading through Heroic Feat resolution rules in Castle Falkenstein multiple times, I'm still quite confused how it works exactly.

1. When a player performs Heroic Feat, she uses one or more cards from her hand, which bonus depends on matching suit. Host also plays one card from his hand, but:

   - a) Does the host have to match suit to type of feat as well, or does it always work with full effect?
   - b) Is the player choosing his card first or after host or do they do it simultaneously?
2. Is there some special rule about combining non-matching suits? In one place it seems that all non-matching suit cards are worth one point each. In another, it says,

   > you can combine those Spades and Clubs and add them to your Ability just like you would if you had used a Heart,

   which hints at equivalence of combined suits to matching suit.
3. Is there anything discouraging players (mechanically) from dumping all low cards for extra points (even non-matching suits) on irrelevant activities to stack their hands with high value cards in preparation for more important tasks?